# Optimize or Replace Bitmap.setPixel

Tags: android, optimization, bitmap

I'm creating a heatzone bitmap from raw data. To do that i convert each value of my rawdata into a color then i affect it to a pixel of a bitmap :

```
for(int i = 0; i < this.heatDatas.length; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < this.maxY; j++)
    {
        ratio = this.heatDatas[i][j] / (double) this.maxValue;

        ratio = ratio * this.nbIndexColors;
        idxColor1 = (int) Math.floor(ratio);
        idxColor2 = idxColor1 + 1;
        distance = ratio - idxColor1;

        r = (int) ((colors[idxColor2][0] - colors[idxColor1][0]) * distance + colors[idxColor1][0]);
        g = (int) ((colors[idxColor2][1] - colors[idxColor1][1]) * distance + colors[idxColor1][1]);
        b = (int) ((colors[idxColor2][2] - colors[idxColor1][2]) * distance + colors[idxColor1][2]);

        bmp.setPixel(i, j, Color.argb(this.alpha, r, g, b));

    }
}
```

This is working , but it's really slow (around 800ms for 512*512 bitmap on nexus 5). After some investigation it seems that `bmp.setPixel(i, j, Color.argb(this.alpha, r, g, b));` took almost 50% of the total execution time. `Color.argb()` seems to be negligible.

What should i do to get better performances ?

Thanks

Note : The aim of this code is to display a heatzone hover an imageview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SetPixel` has a big overhead. It is usually much faster to get a copy of the bitmap (`getPixels`) or create it from scratch, modify it and copy back (`setPixels`).

Comment: That was it ! it decreased the processing time by 4